# I can not deploy nodeJs frontend to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku-cli, lite-server

I am running a nodejs frontend-only website that uses lite-server. as I am trying to deploy it with git in CLI, it shows me the error:

**Did not detect a bs-config.json or bs-config.js override file. Using lite-server defaults...Couldn't open a browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a headless environment, you might want to set the open option to false)**

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Why are you  using `lite-server` in the backend? Use express to serve all the static files! See [Serving Static Files with Express](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html)

Comment: The error message exactly describes what you have to do, doesn't it? Hence, this question doesn't show any research effort.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this error because you are running your project in the headless environment and lite-server uses BrowserSync and its default behavior is to open the browser. However, It allows for configuration overrides via a local bs-config.json or bs-config.js file in your project. You can prevent the browser from opening by [setting option open to `false`](https://browsersync.io/docs/options) in the gulpfule.js file.

```
open: false
```

for more information refer to https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).